# Can I group Multiple stored procedures based on Column in brand new proc ? to avoid duplicate results?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, grouping

The goal is to get one results out of those three stored procedures by grouping them by Id to avoid duplication!

I am having three stored procedure , they returns same tables with different results based on the logic, I have created. I am stuck on how to filter the results to avoid duplication, and return one table with all of them (filtered based on Id Col).

```
ALTER  PROC [dbo].[Recommendation]
          @SurveyInstanceId INT

AS
/*
        DECLARE
            @SurveyInstanceId INT = 74

        EXECUTE [dbo].[recommendation]
                  @SurveyInstanceId 
*/


EXECUTE [dbo].[Resources_Question10Answers]
@SurveyInstanceId 

EXECUTE dbo.Resources_Question11Answers
@SurveyInstanceId

EXECUTE [dbo].[Resources_Question1Answers] 
@SurveyInstanceId
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can INSERT the results of a stored procedure into a temp table or table variable, and then send the results of a query from that table to the client.

eg:

```
ALTER  PROC [dbo].[Recommendation]
          @SurveyInstanceId INT

AS
/*
        DECLARE
            @SurveyInstanceId INT = 74

        EXECUTE [dbo].[recommendation]
                  @SurveyInstanceId 
*/
begin
  set nocount on;
  declare @results table (id int, ...)

  insert into @results
  EXECUTE [dbo].[Resources_Question10Answers]
  @SurveyInstanceId 

  insert into @results
  EXECUTE dbo.Resources_Question11Answers
  @SurveyInstanceId

  insert into @results
  EXECUTE [dbo].[Resources_Question1Answers] 
  @SurveyInstanceId

  select id, ...
  from @results 
  group by id
end
```

Comment: Thank You David, that's exactly what I was trying to achieve.